The edge chromatic number of a graph which has $2n + 1$ vertices, more than $kn$ edges, and the maximum degree $k$.

Find the chromatic index of a graph $G$ if $G$ has $2n+1$ vertices,
more than $kn$ edges, and $k$ is the maximum degree of $G$.

I am faced with such a difficult problem for me in graph theory class.
Here is the question: Given a graph $G$, with $2n + 1$ vertices. The number of edges incident with one vertex is at most $k$. And G has more than $kn$ edges. Please calculate the edge chromatic number of $G$.
I have no ideas how to solve this question. All I know is Vizing's theorem: $$\Delta(G) \leq \chi^{\prime}(G)\leq \Delta(G) + 1$$
I guess here maybe $\Delta(G) + 1$.
Actually, I can imply that the number of vertices whose degree is $k$ is at least $2n + 1 - k$. Because the condition $\epsilon(G) > kn$ need to satisfy. And assume that there are t vertices whose degree is $k$, then
$$
\frac{tk + 2n(k - 1)}{2} > kn,
$$
then induces $t > 2n + 1 - k$.

A good start might be to understand the edge chromatic number of $K_{2n+1}$, as a special case.
